# How to create element's Xpath using different search ( cssSelector / tag / ClassName )

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to find an element using a differect cssSelector / tag  / ClassName amd them get it's xpath value ( to be more specific, I have a website where when a day changes, one of the classes change it's class) here is what do I meean:

```
<tr>
<td> 1.1.2019 </td>
<td> 2.1.2019 </td>
<td class="active"> 3.1.2019 </td>
<td> 4.1.2019 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> 10 </td>
<td> </td> #Here
<td> </td>
</tr>
```

I want to according to where is that "active class", click the table under it. ny idea how to do so ?

short version of what I want :

> Find element using cssSelector
>
> Get this element's Xpath <- the problem
>
> click it using edited xpath

**I want to GET XPATH OF LOCATED ELEMENT , not to locate it using Xpath**

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't make much sense. If you located the element with css selector you already have it, there is  no point relocating it with a different locator.

Comment: the thing is that I want to locate it, to know on which position according to xpath it is to locate element in a table under it

Comment: You want to locate the line marked `#Here` by the relative position to `class="active"`? if `class="active"` is in third index you want to click the third index in the other table?

Comment: yes thats what am i looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can find the index by locating all the `<td>` elements in the first row and check wich one has the index

```
List<WebElement> columns = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[td[@class='active']]/td")); # just an example, can be any other locator
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < columns.getSize() ; i++) {
    String attribute = columns.get(i).getAttribute("class")
    if (attribute != null && attribute.equals("active")) {
        index = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a bit different thing right now. to be more specific, I am looking for something what can get me that xpath to edit it later ( wanna use it dynamicaly )

Comment: here it is explained a bit better <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54687679/how-can-i-get-the-xpath-directly-from-accessed-element-using-different-selector>