# How can I get the XPATH directly from accessed element using different selector

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

**BEFORE YOU MARK IT AS A DUPLICATE, KEEP IN MIND THAT THIS IS A DIFFERENT PROBLEM !!! [How to create element's Xpath using different search ( cssSelector / tag / ClassName )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54671248/how-to-create-elements-xpath-using-different-search-cssselector-tag-class) I KNOW ABOUT THIS QUESTION, BUT I AM LOOKING FOR DIFFERENT ANSWER NOW THAN I WAS LOOKING FOR BEFORE**

I would like to find an element using a differect method ( cssSelector / tag  / ClassName ) and then get it's xpath value ( to be more specific, I have a website where day changes and one of classes change it's class) here is what do I meean:

```
<tr>
<td> 1.1.2019 </td>
<td> 2.1.2019 </td>
<td class="active"> 3.1.2019 </td> # I want this one's Xpath
<td> 4.1.2019 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> 10 </td>
<td> </td> #Here is element i want to get latr
<td> </td>
</tr>
```

I want to according to where is that "active class", click the table under it. ny idea how to do so ?

short version of what I want :

> Find element using cssSelector
>
> **Get this element's Xpath <- the problem**
>
> click it using edited xpath

**I want to GET XPATH OF LOCATED ELEMENT , not to locate it using Xpath**

I have asked similar question here : [How to create element's Xpath using different search ( cssSelector / tag / ClassName )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54671248/how-to-create-elements-xpath-using-different-search-cssselector-tag-class) , but I have notice that the code is not effective, because it has to itterate through the loop. Yes that one work, but I think there is a way how to get Xpath dynamicaly.

```
<tr>
<td> 0 </td>
<td> 10 </td>
<td> 0 </td>
<td> 0 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 0 </td>
<td> 0 </td>
<td> 0 </td>
<td> 0 </td>
</tr>
```

The thing I want to do is that where you can see that 10, I want get its Xpath and then just edit a row ( row + 1 )

Comment: @DebanjanB , there is no answer on how to get the XPATH dynamicaly

Comment: You seem to have an accepted and upvoted answer there and this question is the exact duplicate of that question.

Comment: Yeah true , my bad, I have just declined the answer